# unable to centralize dropdownmenu using CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I know there are many posts on centralizing a drop down menu. However, after trying all the various solutions, it seems that I'm still missing something. I got the code of a dropdownmenu from some free website as follows:

```
#nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 6px 0;
line-height: 100%;
border-radius: 2em;
-webkit-border-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius: 2em;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
background: #000080; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3090C7', endColorstr='#000080'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3090C7), to(#000080)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3090C7, #000080); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
border: solid 1px #6d6d6d;
}

#nav li 
{
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 0 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
/* main level link */
#nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e7e5e5;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
/* main level link hover */
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background: #d1d1d1; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ebebeb', endColorstr='#a1a1a1'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ebebeb), to(#a1a1a1)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #a1a1a1); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
    color: #444;
    border-top: solid 1px #f8f8f8;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}
/* sub levels link hover */
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

#nav ul a:hover {
    background: #0399d4 !important; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#04acec', endColorstr='#0186ba'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba)) !important; /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #04acec, #0186ba) !important; /* for firefox 3.6+ */
    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
    background: #ddd; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cfcfcf'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#cfcfcf)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #cfcfcf); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 185px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}
/* level 3+ list */
#nav ul ul {
    left: 181px;
    top: -3px;
}
/* rounded corners for first and last child */
#nav ul li:first-child > a {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 9px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 9px;
}

#nav ul li:last-child > a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 9px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 9px;
}
/* clearfix */
#nav:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#nav {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 15%;
margin-top: 20px;
}

html[xmlns] #nav {
display: block;
}

* html #nav {
height: 1%;
}
```

I tried to embed the menu with div having style of using margin-left and margin-right as auto but it still could not work probably due to the use of float:left.

Sorry if it this question seems repeated. I'm still new to CSS so I hope some kind soul can help me out here! Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hey here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/ueVr8/

With or without the #menu {} part, it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#nav {
   margin: 0;
}

#menu {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Your updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueVr8/1/)**.

Comment: wow it was that easy? I swear I used that text-align property before. Guessed I messed it up with other properties concurrently.

Thanks Barnee!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the desired effect is, but using your #menu style, you can move that nav wherever you want:

```
#menu {
    width:600px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

I just did a background color so you can see where your nav is in relation to the div. Post any other HTML you have so I can make changes if this isn't what you want.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for your answer. But what I'm trying to achieve is to make the dropdownmenu appear in the middle (horizontally) of the browser instead of trying to manually adjust it as it will not look the same on different browsers with different resolution.